# Flashplayer not refreshing in chrome or IE when src changes

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Here is the web page I'm working on: http://sebastianbiermanlytle.com/music.htm

When you click the arrows on the sides of the media players, a javascript changes the source. All of the soundcloud players are refreshing as they are supposed to, but the mixcloud plugins (under "Full 1+ Hour Sets") are not when using chrome or ie (and probably safari), but are refreshing fine in Mozilla. If you inspect the element, you can see that the src and value attributes are changing as they should when the arrows are pressed - the players are just not refreshing to show the new content.

How can I get these players to refresh?

UPDATE:

This code works:

```
var curSet=0;
var sets = ['<object>....</object>', '<object>...</object>',....];
function nextSet(direction){
     ....//update curSet value
     $('#firstSet').html(sets[curSet]);
}
```

Comment: What's `curSet` here? Could you try logging `sets(curSet)` value to see is there some problems with it? The syntax looks ok to me, would be great to check it within jsFiddle, though.

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, I'm using the same code for all my other media players. Also, the div is still updating fine, its inside just gets changed to a string instead of an html object

Comment: How does this string look like? Can you literally check what's the difference between the string with which `$('#firstSet).html` works just fine and with which it doesn't?

Comment: The strings are identical. It works when it is hard coded into the function, but doesn't when I get it from the array

Comment: Ahhh wait, I was calling the wrong array. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't work in Safari either... Unfortunately it's a known behavior: check [this discussion](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=209730), for example. The only way to get past it is to move manipulation on the higher level. ) You wrap your dynamic elements in `<div>` element, like this:

```
<div id="flash-container">
  <object ...>
  <embed...></embed>
  </object>
</div>
```

... then completely refresh a *container* with the new flash object (with the required `src` value) each time a control fires:

```
$('#flash-container')
  .html('<object ...><param value="new src" ...><embed ... src="new src">')
```

Hope this'll help. )

Comment: Hard coding an object into your code works, but I need to use a variable and access an array. My array isn't working - see my edit for the code. Any ideas?